# У слайдера не работает прокрутка влево и не работает выпадающий список

Tags: javascript, jquery

В слайдере динамически добавляются/удаляются табы. В какой-то момент, прокруртка и выпадающее меню у кнопки "добавить услугу" перестает работать.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Возникает ошибка Cannot read property 'offsetLeft' of undefined.
В какой-то момент не высчитывается `this.current_position` в строке 117.

```
this.$wrapper.css('left', this.$tabs[this.current_position].offsetLeft*-1);
```

В чем может быть проблема?

Полный код [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/lilubanana/31wLs73L/)

**UPD** прокрутка и выпадающий список изначально работают, только после добавления/удаления нескольких табов все ломается

Comment: в коде не увидел ограничений для this.current_position следовательно элемента с таким номером может не существовать

Comment: какие ограничения?

Comment: @MarinaVoronova где-то должна быть у вас проверка выхода за пределы типа `if (position > this.current_position) return;`

Comment: @MarinaVoronova строки 104 и 108 до какой величины убавлять и прибавлять можно? this.current_position++;

Comment: табы динамически добавляются и удаляются, их всегда разное количество

Comment: @MarinaVoronova, но в каждый конкретный момент времени вы знаете сколько у вас табов.

Comment: да, `this.total` считает количество табов

Comment: тогда в чем проблема проверить что текущий счетчик остался меньше чем общее количество???

Comment: @MarinaVoronova вам Grundy уже писал об этой ошибке *Так как нигде не проверяются границы, а выполняется просто увеличение или уменьшение счетчика, то, вполне возможно, в какой-то момент его значение становится либо больше максимального индекса* вот разное количество или длина  и должно быть ограничением сверху и -1 снизу всегда

Comment: считает не корректно, на один меньше

Comment: нет, ограничений никаких нет, табов может быть сколько угодно

Comment: У вас есть ограничения, `current_position` - должен быть в интервале от `0` до `this.total`

Comment: строка 111 должна быть if(this.current_position >= this.total) this.current_position = this.total-1;
   if(this.current_position < 0) this.current_position = 0;

Comment: так? `this.current_position <= this.total` .

Comment: просто `<`, потому что индексация с `0`

Comment: вроде работает. спасибо большое!

Comment: @Grundy: я переоткрыл вопрос. Пожалуйста, опубликуйте ответ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решилась благодаря этому коду:

```
if(this.current_position >= this.total)
        this.current_position = this.total-1;
    if(this.current_position < 0)
        this.current_position = 0;
```

Спасибо рони за помощь!